# One SSL certificate per site

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, certificate

I have 2 sites published in IIS7.

I have also imported 2 certificates, to later associate with the corresponding sites.

I edited the binding on the first site to port 443 and certificate 1.

When I try to edit the second site binding to port 443 and certificate 2, I get a message informing me that there is another certificate associated with that binding.

Why can't I edit the host name like for HTTP?

Comment: Using host headers + single IP?, if so the host header is itself encrypted when it reaches IIS so there is no way for it to determine which binding/cert to use.

Comment: A binding (IP:port) can only map to one certificate. This is completely different from HTTP, where you can add different host headers. To host multiple HTTPS sites on one binding, you need to use a wildcard certificate. Or instead, you use multiple IPs to create multiple bindings first, and then you can bind different certificates and sites to different bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have 1 cert per IP:PORT combination.

You need to either change the IP or the port your web service is listening on.

Comment: Thanks... That's the only option since i don't have a wildcare certificate... Thanks!

Comment: I have the same scenario. Changed the port number to 442 and the website opens in server. But accessing from outside says (domain name with port)- This site can’t be reached and (domain without port) - HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.